# Cant find MouseEventArgs

Tags: c#, blazor

I have been following along with [Create and use ASP.NET Core Razor components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

I am having an issue with this section

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">@Title</div>
    <div class="panel-body">@ChildContent</div>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnClick">
        Trigger a Parent component method
    </button>
</div>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<MouseEventArgs> OnClick { get; set; }
}
```

I keep getting the following error

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'MouseEventArgs' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    BlazorList  D:\Development\BlazorApp1\BlazorList\Pages\ShowListComponent.razor  19  Active

Comment: You need this (or it's razor equivalent) - `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web` - [source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/3.0-preview9/src/Components/Web/src/Web/MouseEventArgs.cs)

Comment: Add a using statement for Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web in your top level _Imports.razor file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event names have been changed in Preview 9

from the blog (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/asp-net-core-and-blazor-updates-in-net-core-3-0-preview-9/):

> Replace Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.UIEventArgs with
>   System.EventArgs and remove the “UI” prefix from all EventArgs derived
>   types (UIChangeEventArgs -> ChangeEventArgs, etc.).

So preview 8 and below need the UI prefix on the event name and the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.UIEventArgs namespace.

preview 9 does not need the UI prefix on the event name. and requires the namespace System.EventArgs